# MySQL select exclude specific result

Tags: mysql, select, join

Maybe the title isn't really clear but I couldn't really get up with a proper naming for it.

I'm trying to select all friends of a person in a table with the following tables:

```
Table friends
column name user1
column name user2
```

I got the query down to the following

```
SELECT users1.username,users2.username FROM friend_request
 JOIN users AS users1 ON friend_request.user1 = users1.id
  INNER JOIN users AS users2 ON friend_request.user2 = users2.id
```

However this obviously returns both names.

```
Foobar | Dummy
```

How can I exclude/get the friend in question in one result?
To clarify if user1.username isn't what I'm looking for show users.2username and verse visa.

```
Dummy
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I'm not sure which of the 2 columns contains the correct user. I'm looking for Dummy but when I join them I get Foobar and Dummy but I just want to know Dummy. As foobar is the one looking up his own friends. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just remove `users1.username` from the list of columns that you're `SELECT`ing?

Comment: This sounds like a self-referencing CTE which I don't believe MySQL supports.

Comment: Could you clarify with some table data? I'm not quite clear on the expected outcome.

Comment: As I'm foobar I dont need the foobar in the result cause my name is already known. The motivation is just to select data you need and exclude the rest and figuring out if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get what you want... do a union.  The first query applies a where clause where the person you are starting with is expected in the "user2" field, and thus you are joining on the "Other" person (user1 field).  The union then applies the reverse... looking for the primary person in the 1st position (user1), but doing a join on the user2 field (other person)

```
SELECT 
      u.username
   FROM 
      friend_request fr
         JOIN users u 
            ON fr.user1 = u.id
   where
      fr.user2 = ThePrimaryPerson
UNION
SELECT 
      u.username
   FROM 
      friend_request fr
         JOIN users u 
            ON fr.user2 = u.id
   where
      fr.user1 = ThePrimaryPerson
```

Comment: People have always told me unions are the start of bad practice. Is this the case? Should I stay away from this or use it as I see fit?

Comment: @John, They can be bad, but for a very small limited set, such as this where you don't know which side the "PrimaryPerson" is in, its almost the same as doing an IF( user1= PrimaryPerson, user2.name, user1.name) and having a where clause where user1=PrimaryPerson or user2=PrimaryPerson.